# choosing the right color

Tags: visible-light, reflection

Context: My room is being painted, and i sit and study in a corner of the room, surrounded by walls on 2 sides, such that i am facing the wall. A tube light is at my 4-5 o'clock, and a door(transparent) at my 7 o'clock. These are the only two sources of light. There is a TV mounted just in front of my desk.

Problem: I want to paint only one wall with a dark color and the rest with a light yellowish green color. Now, which wall should be painted with the dark color so as to maximize light in the corner?? IE, the one facing me, on which the TV is mounted, or any other?

Comment: it is interior designing with a hint of physics, and thats why it is here... :D

Comment: The exact answer must depend on the actual dimensions of the walls, distances, the lumens of the light sources and the directions of the light sources, whether the sunlight is direct or indirect. A desk light is the usual answer.

Comment: Try to color the wall which you face in a dark color as it will be less bright and it will be come for table for your eye's and you will fell comfortable in watching the T.V.. Color the wall on which light is mounted as it will reflect more light and try to give a more tint of green to the color as our eye is most sensitive to green light and colour your roof with a light color it will reflect light directly from the top to the desk. Hope I helped you

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the answer, but to me it seems you should paint in black one of the two wall containing a source light. I would paint in black the window wall, since painting the tube light wall could absorb partially the light coming from the window, but painting it yellow/green gives it the chance to reflect partially the light from the window (I'm assuming green walls reflect more light than the black wall, as should be). In addition the light from the wall cames from the outside, but the light from the lamp cames from inside, so it's important that the wall behind the lamp should be definitely reflective.

Comment: So, as i said, I have a tube light and big doorframe(size=half a wall) on the opposite sides, and 3rd wall perpendicular to both, and the desk against the wall opposite to it. Now, on which wall should dark colors be given ??

Comment: the wall which you face